# How can I use Cinema 4D models in Android and iOS games?

Tags: android, 3d, ios, assets

How can I convert Cinema 4D animation or models to use in games for Android and iOS SDK?What kind of format is required for developing games for these platforms?
If I make a dancing character, do I need to make separate animation for all the steps and moves?